# Detect url params changes in sveltekit 2

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I've been searching for quite long and I haven't found a solution yet.

I have a restaurant (menu/foods) CRUD app, where the "foods" section in the menu is the most important one. Inside the "foods" page I have a sidebar menu that contains: "menus" and "categories", where you can switch between different menus and categories.

I'm using the same page to display the different menus/categories due it will be client side loaded/cached, so I'm using url params to differentiate which data I should fetch.

Once a category or menu item is clicked in the sidebar, the url params are updated like: `?menu=foo&cat=bar`, at the main page level I'm trying to detect those changes but I'm not able to. I understand that the `$page.url.searchParams` is a readable store, so using `$: cat = $page.url.searchParams.get("cat")` is not reactive.

Btw I'm using goto for updating the params into the url. I need to make those changes visible when the user is navigating using the browser arrow buttons, in that way I can display the right data for that specific menu and category.

After read a lot of comments on google, I haven't been able to find the most accurate solution for this.

I'm aware of the `onNavigate, afterNavigate` life cycle functions. I'm wondering whether is that one the right path or not.

I'm using sveltekit 2.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: "so using `$: cat = $page.url.searchParams.get("cat")` is not reactive." - That is reactive.

Comment: You should always load your data in the [load()](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) function. SvelteKit will re-run that function each time the URL changes in such a way that it might yield another result.

Comment: `$: cat = $page.url.searchParams.get("cat")` is not reacting for some reason :( ... about the load function, when you change the url params the load function is not called. it stays in the same page, according to the docs.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, I was setting the new value in some other place like: `$page.url.searchParams.set("cat", newValue)`, before call the `goto` function.